# Are there any naming conventions for helper functions in modules?

Tags: coding-standards

I'm writing a module and I need to create an auxiliary (helper) function, but I don't know which is the best name to my function.

Should I name my function like:

```
function _MODULE_my_function
```

or:

```
function MODULE_my_function()
```

I usually use `_MODULE_my_function()` but there is a standard for this?

There is not reference about this in the [Drupal Coding Standards](https://www.drupal.org/coding-standards#functdecl) or in the [Naming your modules, functions, and variables](https://www.drupal.org/node/299070) article.

Comment: I've never heard of `auxiliary functions` what are they? Doing a google search, I couldn't find anything concrete.

Comment: @NoSssweat for my a function that is not a hook implementation

Comment: Ah ok, hmmm, I've seen both versions, and looks like you're right, there is nothing explicit in the docs.

Comment: @NoSssweat the name auxiliary it's fine?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/663368/295112

Comment: @Kevin thx kevin, but that's for **private [methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841605/what-is-a-difference-between-a-method-and-a-function)** not functions

Comment: There are two answers in there pertaining to Drupal, specifically. Its largely to hide the function from the rest of the system, and to prevent accidental hooking.

Comment: `the name auxiliary it's fine?` @AdrianCidAlmaguer probably, I actually don't know what the Drupal lingo is for them. Based on Aram's answer seems you're right, for Drupal they are called Helper/Auxialiary functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How to name a function is described in [Naming Conventions](https://www.drupal.org/coding-standards#naming) which says:

> Functions should be named using lowercase, and words should be separated with an underscore. Functions should in addition have the grouping/module name as a prefix, to avoid name collisions between modules.

That is valid for hooks and other functions implemented from the module.

For functions that are not hooks, you could also prefix them with an underscore, right before the grouping/module name. If you do it, you are saying to the developers of other modules that the function is not supposed to be called from other modules, but it is *private* for the module defining it.
This is a practice followed from PHP which is also followed from Drupal. For example, `theme()` had been renamed `_theme()`, before being removed, to make clear it was a private functions modules should not call. It's described in [`theme()` renamed to `_theme()` and should not be called directly](https://www.drupal.org/node/2195739).

> The direct callability of `theme()` was removed in favor of building render arrays consistently. It has been renamed to `_theme()` and is for internal use only. Build render arrays instead of using `_theme()` in your code for the following reasons.
>
> Calling the `_theme()` function directly raises several issues:
>
> - It circumvents caching.
> - It circumvents defaults of types defined in `hook_element_info()`, including attached assets
> - It circumvents the `pre_render` and `post_render` stages.
> - It circumvents Javascript states information.

Comment: So, the best way is use an underscore?

Comment: The keyword being `could`, so it seems the conclusion is that it's up to you and there is no standard. `If you do it, you are saying to the developers of other modules that the function is not supposed to be called from other modules` is this somewhere in the docs? or where did you learn this from? Is this some sort of an unwritten rule? or is this PHP rule?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer There is no _best way_. If your functions are not supposed to be called from other modules, you add an underscore to their names.

Answer (score 2):

I believe I have seen it on a few places that helper functions should be prefixed with an underscore. This is how you distinguish between them and other callbacks / main functions, plus you make it impossible to accidentally name something after a hook.

I've been using this system for years and is in my [custom module boilerplate](https://github.com/aramboyajyan/drupal7-boilerplate/blob/master/boilerplate.helpers.inc) as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks Aram I will wait for other answer, for the moment I take your advice